# Regex to find specific word

Tags: python, json

I have a large file that contains multiple entries that look like these below:

```
{"author":["frack113"],"description":"Detects a Sysmon configuration change, which could be the result of a legitimate reconfiguration or someone trying manipulate the configuration","ruleId":"8ac03a65-6c84-4116-acad-dc1558ff7a77","falsePositives":["Legitimate administrative action"],"from":"now-360s","immutable":false,"outputIndex":".siem-signals-default","meta":{"from":"1m"},"maxSignals":100,"riskScore":35,"riskScoreMapping":[],"severity":"medium","severityMapping":[],"threat":[{"tactic":{"id":"TA0005","reference":"https://attack.mitre.org/tactics/TA0005","name":"Defense Evasion"},"framework":"MITRE ATT&CK®","technique":[]}],"to":"now","references":["https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon"],"version":1,"exceptionsList":[],"index":["winlogbeat-*"],"query":"(winlog.channel:\"Microsoft\\-Windows\\-Sysmon\\/Operational\" AND winlog.event_id:\"16\")","language":"lucene","filters":[],"type":"query"},"schedule":{"interval":"5m"}}
```

And I am working on a python program to detect the string after the word "query", so for example in

```
"query":"(winlog.channel:\"Microsoft\\-Windows\\-Sysmon\\/Operational\" AND winlog.event_id:\"16\")"
```

I am trying to detect `(winlog.channel:\"Microsoft\\-Windows\\-Sysmon\\/Operational\" AND winlog.event_id:\"16\")` and I have multiple of these to detect and then use it to compare against "query" in another file to find if there are any similarities.

I tried using this regex, but is not able to detect "query" at all.

```
(?<=^\"query\":\W)(\w.*)$
```

and

```
(?<='{\"query\"}':\s)'?([^'}},]+)
```

Would appreciate if anyone can give some pointers as I am stuck on this for hours!

Comment: Are you sure that you can't just use `json.load`?

Comment: And what does "doesn't seem to work" mean? In which way exactly does it not work?

Comment: If you share the file, we can help. As stated, might even need regex if it’s json file.

Comment: You are trying to match characters that are not there like `'` and `{` If this is json you could consider a parser. For the current string: `(?<="query":")\([^()]+\)` https://regex101.com/r/3va8gP/1

Comment: @chitown88 Not sure if this is the way to share a file here, but here's the link to the file, its rather a long file : [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/892a5daa464bc1aafebde3927548c5e420220817162424/f0d5ac)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your regex works (in a way)! However, any idea how to have a more robust regex, to detect entries with/without whitespace after ':' as shown here - https://regex101.com/r/9zHzDY/1

Comment: @XynoYoo__ You can match optional whitespace chars around the colon, but in Python re you can change it to a capture group. See https://regex101.com/r/kGOgK4/1

Answer (score 0):

You have the python tag in your question as well - so I am assuming a solution involving python script should be fine.

Given that you have a file data.txt with entries as the given example:

```
{"author":["frack113"],"description":"Detects a Sysmon configuration change, which could be the result of a legitimate reconfiguration or someone trying manipulate the configuration","ruleId":"8ac03a65-6c84-4116-acad-dc1558ff7a77","falsePositives":["Legitimate administrative action"],"from":"now-360s","immutable":false,"outputIndex":".siem-signals-default","meta":{"from":"1m"},"maxSignals":100,"riskScore":35,"riskScoreMapping":[],"severity":"medium","severityMapping":[],"threat":[{"tactic":{"id":"TA0005","reference":"https://attack.mitre.org/tactics/TA0005","name":"Defense Evasion"},"framework":"MITRE ATT&CK®","technique":[]}],"to":"now","references":["https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon"],"version":1,"exceptionsList":[],"index":["winlogbeat-*"],"query":"(winlog.channel:\"Microsoft\\-Windows\\-Sysmon\\/Operational\" AND winlog.event_id:\"16\")","language":"lucene","filters":[],"type":"query"},"schedule":{"interval":"5m"}}
```

Then, you can run the following script to print the required strings.

```
def main():
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            
            line = line.split("query")
            result = line[1]
            result = result.split(")")
            result = result[0][2:]

            print(result)

main()
```

For the example string you have provided, this script prints:

```
"(winlog.channel:\"Microsoft\\-Windows\\-Sysmon\\/Operational\" AND winlog.event_id:\"16\"
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do it:

1. Read in as json, then iterate through the dictionary. 2) Read in as str and regex it.

**1. Read in as json:**

```
import json

file = 'exportedSignal.ndjson'
with open(file, 'r', encoding = 'cp850') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)

queries = []
hits = jsonData['hits']['hits']
for hit in hits:
    if 'query' in hit['_source']['alert']['params'].keys():
        query = hit['_source']['alert']['params']['query']
        queries.append(query)
print(queries)
```

**2. Use Regex:**

```
import re

file = 'exportedSignal.ndjson'
with open(file, 'r', encoding = 'cp850') as f:
    data = f.read()

queries = re.findall('\"query\":\"(.*?)\"', data)
print(queries)
```

**Output:**

Both produce a list of 2006 values from the `"query"` key.

[image]